# Параллакс элементов при скролле

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, вёрстка

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста. Вот есть, например, какой-то блок посередине страницы. И нужно чтобы он при скролле, когда попадает в поле видимости, постепенно сдвигался примерно на 50px вверх, если пользователь скроллит вниз, и на 50px вниз, если пользователь скроллит вверх. 
Но чтобы сдвигался не сразу а постепенно, вместе с прокруткой страницы пользователем. Тоесть как обычный параллакс фона, только блока.

Подскажите, как такое лучше сделать, какие плагины использовать?

Comment: Связанный: [Предложите вариант скролл-эффекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775780/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb-%d1%8d%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0/775898#775898)

Comment: а что вам мешает просто при обработке скролла пересчитывать координату элемента? Как я понимаю вам просто нужно чтобы элемент ехал в обратную сторону, для этого нужно увеличивать значение top элемента на величину скролла помноженную на некий коэффициент, не вижу здесь резона подключать какие-то плагины...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Примерно такой скрипт можно написать

```js
var paralax = document.getElementById("paralax");

/* коэфициент сдвига: 1 сдвиг равный смещению по оси Y, 0 без сдвига */
var moveCoef = 0.5;

window.addEventListener("scroll", scroll);
window.addEventListener("resize", scroll);
scroll();

function scroll() {
  /* берём огнаничивающий прямоугольник паралакса относительно окна (фрейма) */
  var r = paralax.getBoundingClientRect();

  /* центр паралакса */
  var paralaxYCenter = r.y + r.height / 2;
  /* центр экрана */
  var scrollYCenter = window.innerHeight / 2;

  /* Вычисляем смещение */
  var move = (paralaxYCenter - scrollYCenter) * moveCoef - 100;

  paralax.style.backgroundPositionY = move + "px";
}
```

```css
#paralax {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU2R1.jpg);
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: 180%;
}

.space1 {
  height: 160px;
}

.space2 {
  height: 800px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="space1">Скролируй ниже</div>
<div id="paralax"></div>
<div class="space2"></div>
```