# Как работает анимация слоев в этой верстке?

Tags: javascript, html, css3, frontend, parallax

Подскажите пожалуйста что движет этой анимацией слоев? В отладчике не какие значения не меняются + js не используется. Следовательно вопрос в том почему слои двигаются с разной скоростью и что на это влияет. Спасибо!

```
Пример:
```

https://codepen.io/secretgspot/pen/QaGGVp

Comment: Обычный паралакс, почитайте про него и станет все понятно. И почему если движение, это только JS (вопрос риторический)?

Comment: @VladSpirin я знаком с паралаксом. в нем обычно идет привязка к скролу страницы и от него уже анимируются какие либо свойства типа (bgposition translateY и прочее) если можно анимировать скорость не только js, объясните пожалуйста как в этом примере это делается?

Comment: [Гляньте тут, коль лень гуглить](https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/35-pure-css-parallax-websites), освобожусь, будут еще вопросы, отвечу

Comment: @VladSpirin о! кажется это то что нужно! спасибо!

Comment: [Тут вот,](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/775898/262779) показывал как с JS делать, может пригодится, коль данной темой интересуетесь. Не списывайте CSS, достаточно мощный инструмент в умелых руках

Comment: @VladSpirin спасибо! Буду разбираться. Не знаю куда нажать чтобы отметить комент ответом. Только зарегался тут. Если есть желание общаться на тему веб разработки : https://vk.com/id29833736

Comment: Коммент ответом отметить невозможно, для этого надо оформить полноценным ответом. Главное, что я вам помог и вы разобрались, или теперь знаете куда двигаться. Обращайтесь. Я с фронта по чуть-чуть спрыгиваю. Объем знаний растет, вижу возможности иные.

Comment: @VladSpirin в сторону fullstack ?

Comment: @VladSpirin интересная сфера. мало слышал о ней. на данный момент я занимаюсь разработкой браузерной игры кликалки, в которой задействуется и фронт и бек. Приходится все писать. Проблема в том, что когда сильно углубляешься в один язык, начинаешь забывать что то в другом :D

Comment: @VladSpirin можно задам еще вопрос если вы в сфере фронта очень давно: Писать на ванильном js или на jq ? к примеру слушатель addEventListener или on ? понятно что jq это кроссбр и тп, но как лучше? потому что я изучаю и то и то и непонятно когда что применить. Спасибо

Comment: @VladSpirin спасибо!

Answer (score -2):

Скорость движения слоя определяется сочетанием значений перспективы и перемещения по оси Z. Элементы с отрицательным значением `translateZ` прокручиваются медленнее, чем с положительным. Чем дальше это значение от 0, тем более выраженным получится параллакс-эффект (то есть при `translateZ(-10px)` прокрутка происходит медленнее, чем при `translateZ(-1px)`).